# how to make bootstrap 3 carousel touch slide without jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, touch

how to make bootstrap 3 carousel touch ?

how do you make bootstrap carousel touch slide without jquery mobile ?

Is there a way ? to tweak that code to enable fingers to swap the slides ?

Comment: Does this help ? Its not jQuery but as a technology angular is definitely worth a look at. It works so well with bootstrap sites. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel

Comment: True, with ng-touch and swipe but without ? Do you have any suggestion? I have found hammer.js. What is your advice ?